# Время полного обхода графа

Tags: алгоритм, графы

На интервью попался интересный вопрос.

Точная формулировка:

> Существует ли алгоритм не выше `O(N^k)`, где `k` - некоторое
>   натуральное число (константа), получающий на вход произвольный связный
>   граф с `N` вершинами (одну из них назовем особой) и строящий маршрут
>   минимальной длинны, который начинается и заканчивается в особой
>   вершине и включает все остальные вершины ровно по одному разу? Если
>   да, то можете ли вы указать `k`?

Возможности задавать уточняющие вопросы у меня не было, так что это все что есть.

Есть подозрение что такого алгоритма вообще нет, так как если граф произвольный, то не факт что возможность обойти его полностью пройдя по каждой вершине только 1 раз вообще существует.

Я на вопрос ответить не смог, но правильный ответ меня все же интересует. Есть идеи?

Comment: NP-полная задача коммивояжера. Если вы доказательно ответите на этот вопрос, не забудьте уделить толику от обещанной за ее решение премии за то, что подсказал, что вы сможете ее получить :) Лет 26 назад примерно так же звучал вопрос - можно ли в натуральных числах решить уравнение x^n+y^n=z^n для n > 2 :)

Comment: @Harry приму к сведению)). Но мне кажется это не совсем задача коммивояжера так как мы 1. Возвращаемся обратно к особой вершине в то время когда коммивояжер останавливается на последней. 2. Коммивояжер кажется не связан обязательством проходить по всем узлам точно 1 раз. 3. Что если этот "произвольный граф" будет связанным списком из 3х узлов? Как нам тогда возвращаться обратно к исходному узлу не тронув 2й узел повторно.

Comment: Уберите требование минимального пути - все равно получите NP-полную задачу о гамильтонговом цикле https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8 Вот формулировка задачи коммивояжера - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: @Harry, ну вроде тут не сказано, что эту задачу надо решить за разумное время и вполне можно положить полный перебор всех вариантов. Ну будет у нас k = N! и время выполнения больше времени существования вселенной, ответ всё равно ведь есть. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: По вашим возражениям - 1. нет, коммивояжер возвращается домой, см. ссылку выше. 2. "Как правило, указывается, что маршрут должен проходить через каждый город только один раз" - оттуда же. 3. В этом случае гамильтонова цикла нет, поставленная задача решения не имеет.

Comment: Спрошено - *существует ли алгоритм не выше O(N^k)* (цитата из вашего вопроса). N! - это, согласно формуле Стирлинга, вообще (n/e)^n*sqrt(n), и уж никак не N^k...

Comment: @Harry я приравнял k факториалу, полная будет как N^(N!), формально выполняя условие.

Comment: @AlexKrass B с каких это пор N! стало *константой*?... Тогда у нас *любой* алгоритм имеет O(1)...

Comment: @Harry да, согласен, был неправ.